# Inserting multiple rows to database using mvc5 web application

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to add multiple rows of data and pass it to the table in database along with another item to a different table. Below is the struct of the databse:

```
User Table

userid
name

Movie Table

Movieid
userid
moviename

Cinema Table
Movieid
cinemaid
location
time
```

The movietable has 1 to many realtionship with the Cinema table. The user table has one I have four different viewmodels associating to them:

```
UserViewModel
{
    public int userid;
    public string name;
}

MoviewViewModel
{
    public int movieid;
    public int userid;
    public string moviename;
    public List<CinemaViewModel> cinema;
}

CinemaViewModel
{
    public int movieid;
    public int cinemaid;
    public string location;
    public string time;
}

UserandMovieViewModel
{
    public List<MoviewViewModel> movie;
    public UserViewModel user;
}
```

I am passing the userandmoviewmodel from the controller create to the view and would like to add one entry for user and movie, but would like to add multiple entries to the Cinema database from that single page. it works fine when i add a single entry to cinema. however i would like to have the ability to add multiple entries to cinema table when form is posted. I have tried the tutorial below but that doesnt seem to work for create.

http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/

**EDIT**

The code which give null exception

```
 <ul id="movieEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
   @foreach (CinemaViewModel cinemamodel in Model.UserandMovieViewModel.cinema) {
    Html.RenderPartial("MovieEntryEditor", cinemamodel);
      }
 </ul>
 <a id="addAnother" href="#">Add another</a>
```

**EDIT2**

The create controller code

```
[httpget]
public ActionResult Create()
{

 UserViewModel usermodel = new UserviewModel();
 List<MovieViewModel> moviemodel= new List<MovieViewModel>();

 UserandMovieViewModel model = new UserandMovieViewmodel{user = usermodel, movie=moviemodel }


 return View(model)
 }

  [httppost]
   public ActionResult Create(UserandMovieViewmodel model)
   {

   IRepository<User> userrep = new ApplicationRepository<User>();
   IRepository<Movie> userrep = new ApplicationRepository<Movie>();
   IRepository<Cinema> userrep = new ApplicationRepository<Cinema>();

    User user = null;
    Movie movie = null;
    Cinema cinema = null;

    UserViewModel usermodel = model.usermodel;
    MovieViewModel moviemodel= model.moviemodel;
    CinemaViewModel cinemamodel = model.moviemodel.cinema;


    if(ModelState.valid)

    {

     user = new user();

      user.name = usermodel.name;
       userrep.add(user);


      movie = new movie();

      movie.userid = user.userid; (gets from database as its autoappend)
      movie.moviename = moviemodel.moviename;

      movierep.Add(movie);

       cinema = new cinema();

       cinema.movieid = movie.movieid;
        cinema.location = cinemamodel.location;
        cinema.time = cinemamodel.time;

        cinemarep.Add(cinema);

      }

    return View(model);




       }
```

I have written the code from memory as i dont currently have it. Please correct any errors you see.

EDIT 3

Partial View

```
@model Application.ViewModels.CinemaViewModel



<li style="padding-bottom:15px">

   <div style="width: 450px; float: left;">
    <label class="location">
      Location
    </label>
    <span style="margin-left: 26px;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.location)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.location)
    </span>


    <span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.time)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.time)
    </span>

</div>
```

Comment: what is the issue you have encountered?

Comment: when i use this for create, it gives me a system null exception. I am looking to be able to add many cinema listings during the create of user and movie.

Comment: could you please post the code that gives you null reference exception?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have your list as null, so you can try just to new it up in constructor:

```
public class MoviewViewModel
{
    public MoviewViewModel(){
       cinema = new List<CinemaViewModel>();
    }
    public int movieid;
    public int userid;
    public string moviename;
    public List<CinemaViewModel> cinema;
}

public class UserandMovieViewModel
{
    public UserandMovieViewModel(){
        movie = new List<MoviewViewModel>();
    }
    public List<MoviewViewModel> movie;
    public UserViewModel user;
}
```

EDIT:
Your view:

```
<ul id="movieEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
   @if(Model.UserandMovieViewModel.cinema.Any())
   {
       foreach (CinemaViewModel cinemamodel in Model.UserandMovieViewModel.cinema) {
         Html.RenderPartial("MovieEntryEditor", cinemamodel);
        }
   }
   else
   {
       @{ Html.RenderPartial("MovieEntryEditor", new CinemaViewModel()) };
   }
 </ul>
 <a id="addAnother" href="#">Add another</a>
```

Comment: but if there is no entry in the database for cinema, would it not still give null exception. Also will i need to change anything in controller i.e go thorough a for loop ?

Comment: it depends from the way you assigning cinema ViewModel one to cinema from db. If you are using .Select() for this - there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: im not sure i understant .select()

Comment: please post the code through witch you're passing values from your db to view model.

Comment: if you'll add initialization for lists to your view models constructors - I think your problem whould be solved.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it first thing tomorrow morning. fingers crossed it works.

Comment: If it won't - just let me know.

Comment: hi again. its going past the foreach loop now, but is not rendering the partial.

Comment: it's because your 'cinema' list is empty.

Comment: yes but since i am creating not editing, it would  be empty intially

Comment: I see two options for resolving this: 1) add one empty element to 'cinema' collection; 2) on your view - just check if your collection has any elements and if not - just Html.RenderPartial("MovieEntryEditor", new CinemaViewModel());

Comment: doing  Html.RenderPartial("MovieEntryEditor", new CinemaViewModel()); tthis doesnt pass the values im afraid.

Comment: why is that doesn't pass the values? Which values do you want to pass? I've just edited my answer to represent basic idea of view code.

Comment: do i need to change anything in the partial view ?

Comment: I think that there is no need for this.

Comment: I posted my partial view. can you please see, if there is anything worng with it ?

Comment: Why do you need cinemaid and movieid in your CinemaViewModel (you're not using it on your view)? One more thing - if you would try to post the data to server with ordinary form - it won't work because you need to have your input name attribute as location[i], not just location, that's want the post you mention in your question about.